# Collapsing a Spark BorderContainer dynamically does not collapse its children

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

```
protected function lbHideQuery_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (lbHideQuery.selected)
            {
                lbHideQuery.label = "Show Query Panel";
                origHeight = canvas1.height;
                canvas1.height = 0;

            }
            else
            {
                lbHideQuery.label = "Hide Query Panel";
                canvas1.height = origHeight;

            }
        } 
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:LinkButton  label="Hide Query Panel" id="lbHideQuery" toggle="true" click="lbHideQuery_clickHandler(event)"/>
<mx:Canvas id="canvas1" width="100%" height="20%" backgroundColor="0x353356">
<mx:VBox width="16%" height="90" minHeight="0" minWidth="0" id="vgbtns">
        <mx:Button label="Button 1"/>
        <mx:Button label="Button 2"/>
        <mx:Button label="Button 3"/>
</mx:VBox>
```

but in Flex 4 when the BorderContainer collapses the buttons are still visible.

```
            }
        } 
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<mx:LinkButton  label="Hide Query Panel" id="lbHideQuery" toggle="true" click="lbHideQuery_clickHandler(event)"/>
<s:BorderContainer width="100%" height="25%" backgroundColor="0x353356" id="bc1" >
    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout paddingLeft="6"/>
    </s:layout>
    <s:VGroup width="16%" height="90" minHeight="0" minWidth="0" id="vgbtns">
        <s:Button label="Button 1"/>
        <s:Button label="Button 2"/>
        <s:Button label="Button 3"/>

    </s:VGroup>
</s:BorderContainer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (lbHideQuery.selected)
            {
                lbHideQuery.label = "Show Query Panel";
                origHeight = canvas1.height;
                canvas1.height = 0;
                canvas1.visible= false;

            }
            else
            {
                lbHideQuery.label = "Hide Query Panel";
                canvas1.height = origHeight;
                canvas1.visible= true;
            }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. Your solution works but why do I've to set the visibility of the child container to false in Flex 4?

Comment: if this helps, you may to accept answer, an about why: - because the mx or spark logic, in layouts mean that visible components with zero sizes have the same rules as others, and all events are handling in this zero component, but if invisible, its not drawing at all, thats way, you getting different logic, using visibility way.